# Facebook API post link with custom picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I could set custom picture and caption for link. Now it is impossible for v2.9. Is there some kind of workaround without specifying og: tags.

When using Facebook Graph v2.8, you could post a link and display a custom image and not the "og:image".
This was done by adding the picture parameter to the hook.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/me/feed?link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&picture=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FtntOCGkgt98%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg&name=test&message=this%20is%20a%20test&access_token=**********
```

The graph API is at 2.9 and as per the documentations this is still supposed to work [Facebook API doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/post/)

However, it keeps getting overridden by the scraped image. Is anyone else experiencing this problem or have a workaround.? [Facebook API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=POST&path=me%2Ffeed&version=v2.9&link=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&picture=https%3A%2F%2Fi.ytimg.com%2Fvi%2FtntOCGkgt98%2Fmaxresdefault.jpg&name=test&message=this%20is%20a%20test)

Comment: Can't find it now but pretty sure it was deprecated. Just use og-tags.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph publish posts with link and custom picture not working on v2.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103086/facebook-graph-publish-posts-with-link-and-custom-picture-not-working-on-v2-9)

Comment: I will admit that he's asked it in a more presentable way. But I asked the question May 22, that is almost 2 months before July 14. If anything he duplicated my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

picture, name, caption, thumbnail, description are all set to be deprecated.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_9_90_day_deprecations

Comment: WTH ? Why Facebook depreciated this ?

Comment: They made a blog post saying it to combat #fakenews.

Comment: Give me please the link where are the discussions.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/06/27/API-Change-Log-Modifying-Link-Previews/

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead and use Open Graph for posting images with custom description and title.

You can get an insight of the same from this link -> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters?hc_location=ufi

Comment: Thanks, but this is only useful if you own the domain of the page you are posting.

Comment: My links are created dinamicaly, I can't use this :(